# Heroku Ruby Deploys Disabled - Why is using a buildpack_url risky?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, rubygems

I want to push out changes, but it's not completely necessary right now.
Why does Heroku say that setting a custom BUILDPACK_URL is risky?
https://status.heroku.com/incidents/489

Is it risky because it's overriding the block and it's a gamble whether the gems I'm using have been tampered with?

How long would you expect this block to last for? I'm sure the rubygems.org team is working as fast as they can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, it is risky because a malicious gem might be installed from rubygems.org which could compromise your application. However, if you made no changes to your Gemfile/Gemfile.lock since the last deploy you should be fine since rubygems.org will not be hit during deploy.

But unless you really know what you're doing you're better of waiting until the rubygems.org team has checked all gems. It shouldn't take too long. You can follow their progress on [twitter](https://twitter.com/rubygems_status).